# Quick send bookmarks by mail

Tags: firefox, browser-addons

Is there an addon for firefox which provides quickly sending shared bookmarks via e-mail?
I'm not interested in "sync" addons.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such an addon for Firefox at the moment. You may save your bookmarks in `.json` format (Organize Bookmarks > Import and Export > Backup) and attach that file to your email. It shouldn't take more than a minute.

Comment: (or in .html) yes, I knew this option but I'm looking for an instant method.

Answer (score 0):

You can right click a folder in your bookmarks toolbar, copy, and paste into an email. That might work in the bookmarks manager as well. Thunderbird formats the links nicely.